External module adapter for Jumper T20
I have occasionally bought external nano module adapter for Jumper T-Lite

which seems to be incompatible with Jumper T20.

How can I rewire it to work on Jumper T20?

Also interested:

Why in general this adapter is needed (why the necessary circuit is not built into controller itself)?
Are there modules that can be plugged to controller only using wires (without intermediate circuit)?

